# Running two process in one command-line with split-screen

Tags: command-line

I need to split the command prompt window without making two windows. On one side I need a file to be read and on the other side (split with lines) to be command prompt gathering CPU Usage and RAM Usages. Things I need to know if I can do:
   - Gather CPU and RAM Usage from command prompt or batch
   - Have two process running side by side in the same window
   - Read configuration files in a specific format (such as: server-dir=C:\Users...)
   - Have both sides update every second with no glitches in graphics

Could it be done? An example of this would be handle (a minecraft server handler, can be seen here: http://goo.gl/t3741n)

Comment: This question is off-topic (it's an operating system use question, not a programming question). If it were on-topic, it's far too broad in scope; it's a list of a whole lot of requirements of things you need all at once. In addition, it's far too vague. *Could it be done?* is not a question with any value. Possible answers are "Yes, it can", "No, it cannot", or "Possibly" with no other information- which of those three would be of use to you? See this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576).

Comment: there are a bunch of tools that already gather CPU and RAM usage info in the same window. Did you look at `top`, `htop`, `atop`, `glances`, and many others, depending on your OS. Good luck